# MediaRecorder Web API Crash while streaming 60FPS Stream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have the following code to record USB Stream using [MediaRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API in Chromebook Package App.

```
function startVideoRecord()
{
    mIsRecordingStarted = true;

    let options = {mimeType : 'video/webm;codecs=h264'} 

    //Check is h264 supported
    if(! MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType))
    {
            console.log("h264 mimeType is not supported");
            return;
    }

    //create MediaRecorder Instance
    try
    {
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
    }catch(error)
    {
            console.log(error);
            return;
    }

    mMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mMediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data


    //empyt the temp buffer before start recording
    recordedData = [];

}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedData.push(event.data);
  }
}

function StopRecording() {
            mIsRecordingStarted = false;
            mMediaRecorder.stop();

            //Write the recorded data to file and save locally
            const blob = new Blob(recordedData, {type: 'video/webm'});
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const tempAnchor = document.createElement('a');
            tempAnchor.style.display = 'none';
            tempAnchor.href = url;
            tempAnchor.download = 'video.webm';
            document.body.appendChild(tempAnchor);
            tempAnchor.click();
            setTimeout(() => {
                    document.body.removeChild(tempAnchor);
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }, 100);
```

}

Note: *getUserMedia is used to start the stream. Stream preview is working without any flaw.*

When i set my constraints to start stream at 1920 x 1080 at 30 Frames per Seconds, i got my Video Recording working and saved to local successfully.

But when tried with 1920 x 1080 at 60 FPS, i got the chunks pushed to recordedData and web app closed forcefully.

This is tried in Chromebook running Chrome OS version: 73.0.36(official Build). The application is deployed as Chrome Package App.

Can someone help me the cause for crash ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See crbug.com and report it if there are no previous reports.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your suggestion. I have raised a query https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=953626

Comment: As per my recent experiment, when codecs=h264 replaced with codecs=vp8, video recording seems to be working good without any crash.